# Recursive Solution for Reversing Linked List

Tags: algorithm, recursion, data-structures, linked-list

```
void recursiveReverse(struct node** head_ref)
{
struct node* first;
struct node* rest;

/* empty list */
if (*head_ref == NULL)
   return;   

/* suppose first = {1, 2, 3}, rest = {2, 3} */
first = *head_ref;  
rest  = first->next;

/* List has only one node */
if (rest == NULL)
   return;   

/* reverse the rest list and put the first element at the end */
recursiveReverse(&rest);
first->next->next  = first;  

/* tricky step -- see the diagram */
first->next  = NULL;          

/* fix the head pointer */
*head_ref = rest;              
}
```

Above is the code for Reversing Linked List recursively. I understood the program, but at the end *head_ref = rest; is confusing me. Let me elaborate it.

Let's take an example of 1->2->3

```
in first recursion: first=1, rest=2
in second recursion: first=2, rest=3
in last recursion: first=3, rest=null
```

and from that point we go back, and in each step we assign *headRef=rest
finally we come back at first step our rest was 2 and we assign *headRef=2
but we need rest point to 3 not 2.
I am sure I am missing something here but I could not resolve this please help me out

I tried by printing the addresses of first and rest.[image shows that after recursion, address of rest doesn't change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CVah6.png)

Thanks in advance.

The above code is from geeksforgeeks... There I commented, but no one helped me.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2ibx.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the address of the `rest` pointer is passed in the recursive call.

By the time you return from recursion, the `rest` pointer changes to point to the 'new' start of the 'remaining-list'.

This means that in your example, rest will be changed to point to element 3 at each backward recursive step.

Comment: I didn't understand... I wrote this on paper. You can see from here http://imgur.com/Dfb46xD.... There I clearly described my doubt. Please help me to understand...

Comment: you can see there that I K1,K2,K3,K4 are the addresses and added '0' at the end for address of Rest

Comment: @LokeshS In your diagram, *head_ref will get K4 because after returning from recursion Rest2 would point to K4, i.e., *head_ref3 = rest2. and *head_ref3 = K4 as you wrote in the diagram.